# How do you randomly generate a number from an array and then use that number in a switch statement in C++?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, srand

I am very new to c++ and I am trying to randomly pick one of my cases to use, but it is going straight to default. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong or maybe a better way to do it. This is my code:

```
class selectingTheVillain {
public:
void theRandomness() {

int theRandomChoice;

int villainArray[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};

int randIndex = 1 + (rand() % 4) ;

villainArray[randIndex] = theRandomChoice;


cout << "Welcome to the Random Dungeon Game!" << endl << endl;

switch (theRandomChoice) {
case 0:
class skeleton skeleton;
skeleton.setSkeletonStats(170, 40, 20, 5);
skeleton.showSkeletonStats();
break;

case 1:
class goblin goblin;
goblin.setGoblinStats(160, 40, 50, 15);
goblin.showGoblinStats();
break;

case 2:
class ghoul ghoul;
ghoul.setGhoulStats(130, 45, 30, 30);
ghoul.showGhoulStats();
break;

case 3:
class stoneGolem stoneGolem;
stoneGolem.setStoneGolemStats(220, 45, 5, 0);
stoneGolem.showStoneGolemStats();
break;

default:
cout << "It did not work" << endl;
break;
}
}
};
```

//my srand is in my main function.

Comment: `villainArray[randIndex] = theRandomChoice;` Shouldn't this be swapped? Also here `int randIndex = 1 + (rand() % 4) ;` you shouldn't add 1.

Comment: You aren't indenting anything, for starters.

Comment: are you sure your code compile ?

Comment: I swapped the two and deleted the +1 and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues in your code.

Firstly, on this line:

```
int randIndex = 1 + (rand() % 4) ;
```

you are generating indexes in the range `1 .. 4`, but you need `0 .. 3`. So simply remove the `+ 1` like this:

```
int randIndex = rand() % 4;
```

Secondly, this assignment:

```
villainArray[randIndex] = theRandomChoice;
```

doesn't modify `theRandomChoice`. You need to do:

```
theRandomChoice = villainArray[randIndex];
```